# python selenium driver.quit() can not quit firefox browser if firefox_profile setted

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-profile

This problem really confused me a lot.
I'm using python selenium do some automatic work. After the work done, i need to close browser(I must use firefox). And I know `driver.close()` is to close current window and `driver.quit()` will close all windows and exit browser. The problem is: it doesn't work for me if i am using **python file.py** to run my code, but work if I setup the driver in **python console**, here not work is to say it just close my url, but the firefox browser not exit. All above tests have setted firefox_profile. 
More, i found if i don't set firefox_profile the first way to run my code also working. I think maybe it's a bug for firefox_profile. Wish someone to save my day.
My code is just like:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)  # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', download_dir)
profile.set_preference(
    'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/octet-stream')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=gecko_dir, firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(someurl)
driver.quit()# which will close my session, my url, my current window but not exit browser
```

the versions i'am using:

- python     3.5.3
- selenium   3.4.3
- firefox    55.0.1
- geckodriver   0.18.0

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `just close my url, but the firefox browser not exit`? Is the Firefox Browser and WebDriver instance getting closed gracefully?

Comment: after the driver.quit() done, my browser can not exit, it still keep one window on, which is a blank window - a "New Tab" no the other things. Is that clear?

Comment: The browser windows initiated by the webdriver instance is bound to get closed (killed) once you invoke `driver.quit()`. So the `blank window` may be a result of some other user interections. Are you on Selenium 3.5.0 with latest GeckoDriver v.0.18.0 and Mozilla Firefox 53.0?

Comment: as i supplement just now, my selenium version 3.4.3 and the geckodriver and firefox are both the latest version. No the others interrections. Problem is still there

Comment: Can you close down all your apps and get a system restart and simply execute your script?

Comment: Oh shit, i'am stupid. There is really some other interaction that I did find. There's another driver opened. thanks a lot

Comment: ok ok, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we work with `Selenium 3.5.0` with latest `GeckoDriver v.0.18.0` and `Mozilla Firefox 53.0`, the browser window(s) initiated by the `WebDriver` instance is bound to get **destroyed (killed)** once you invoke the `quit()` on the `WebDriver` instance.

So the blank window which you are seeing may be a result of either some other user interactions or a dangling instance.

### Recommendation:

You can consider the following steps to start a clean Test Execution:

1. Run `CCleaner` tool to wipe out all the leftovers from your previous executions.
2. Restart your system to start your `Test Execution` on a clean OS environment.
3. Keep the `Test Environment` isolated from other `User Interactions`.